# Does a svn frontend for git exist

Tags: svn, git, integration, typo3

We are planing to migrate our repositories from svn to git. However there are some people using np_subversion which integrates SVN into the TYPO3-Backend.

[np_subversion](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?tx_terfe_pi1%5Bview%5D=search&no_cache=1&tx_terfe_pi1%5Bsword%5D=np_subversion) calls the svn client to make updates, commits, show logs etc.
I am looking for a tool that behaves like the svn client but works on a git repository as its backend. (Kind of git-svn but the other way round)

Alternatively if anyone knows an extension that integrates Git into the TYPO3 Backend I would appreciate that.

Comment: Depending on what your TYPO3 plugin does you might get away with simply aliasing svn commands to the relevant git commands

Comment: It does seem to be possible. [github provides](https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion) svn access to git repositories. I don't know how, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're actually looking for is a svn *server* that is a proxy to git. There have been [plans to implement git-svnserver](http://utsl.gen.nz/git/git-svnserver.txt), and it was a potential project for [SoC 2007](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SoC2007Ideas), [2008](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SoC2008Ideas) and [2009](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SoC2009Ideas#git-svnserver), but as far as I know it was never completed.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That would be great if there would be some implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is Python code to serve a git repository over svn protocol:

http://git.q42.co.uk/git_svn_server.git

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this meets your needs but [Easy Git](http://www.gnome.org/~newren/eg/) (a.k.a. `eg`) is a thin layer (single perl script) that provides a more CVS and SVN-like interface to Git.  Make sure you checkout the [Easy Git for SVN users](http://www.gnome.org/~newren/eg/git-for-svn-users.html) page.  You can also find the code online from the [official repository](http://gitorious.com/eg) at Gitorious.

Answer (score 1):

Some 12 years later, this SO question showed up in the results to my web search along with https://github.com/git-as-svn/git-as-svn.

That project seems active; I have not tried it and I am not related to it. According to their documentation, they are based on or inspired by http://git.q42.co.uk/git_svn_server.git (that is @mab's answer).

And there is https://subgit.com/. It is non-free; I have not tried it and I am not related to it.